# How do you choose direction of moment of inertia?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, conventions, moment-of-inertia

If a car is accelerating forward from rest with no air resistance while weight and normal forces act on the wheels, in which direction is the moment of inertia? Is it positive, clockwise or anti clockwise and why?

The answer is anticlockwise but I can't figure out why since the wheels are turning in the clockwise direction...

Comment: Comment to the question (v4): The notion of CW/CCW moment of inertia seems meaningless (as opposed to, e.g. CW/CCW angular velocity, CW/CCW angular momentum, CW/CCW torque, etc, which make sense).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of how you find this out, the direction is given by the right hand rule. Hold your right hand out in front of you with your thumb pointing left. (Your thumb sort of acts as the rotational axis of the wheel). If you think of the wheel as your guide, in which was does the wheel turn in order to move the car forward?

A.) Anti-clockwise.

Does that make sense? Let me know if it doesn't, I will try an explain a bit better.

Comment: I never undertood the right hand rule but im doing as you said and somehow my fingers are telling me the right answer.

Comment: But i dont understand the last bit. did you say that the wheels are turning anti-clockwise? because they're turning clockwise in the question

Comment: Yeh, so think of a car moving forward and imagine yourself looking at the wheels from the SIDE of the car. (Doesn't matter which side). Now, what way are the wheels turning when the car is moving forward? And in what way are the wheels moving when the car is reversing?

Comment: I wish i could tick both your answers man. Apparently i dont have enough reputation points to upvote an answer so im sorry.

Comment: That's ok. Hopefully my answer is helping you understand this problem from a physical perspective rather than what is prescribed in lecture notes, etc. (I would say that my answer is perhaps the more valid of the two, but I'm inherantly bias).

Comment: i think your bias is influencing me.

Comment: Just remember when the car is moving forward (whether it is accelerating or at constant velocity, or even jerking forward!) the wheels are moving anti-clockwise. When the car is reversing the wheels are moving clockwise. It is perhaps confusing to think, but I would say that our clocks are in fact the wrong way around in this sense! Just to confuse things. My top tip is to always think about the physical question, try and imagine it in your head. That should help.

Comment: I am sorry to continue bothering you but i would be grateful if you can clarify it further. If a car is moving towards the right, the wheels move in the clockwise direction according to what i see in daily life (i even checked a video just now). how is it that they move anticlockwise?

Comment: You say it is moving forward to the left?

Comment: no, to the right.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be anticlockwise; for the torque generated during acceleration by the car makes us jerk backwards.